# TIBCO RV set weight of session on client side

Tags: networking, tcp, multicast, tibco

I was wondering if TIBCO RV allows for clients to set the weight (priority) of their connections.

I read in their documentation that it is possible to set weight to a TCP session so it is prioritized over others. But it was not clear if this is set by the sys admin or can be dynamically changed over time, by a custom header or something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_it is possible to set weight to a TCP session so it is prioritized over others_" If you are referring to QoS, then you can set values in the IP DSCP header field, but that actually does nothin unless the routers are configured to implement your QoS policies (does not work on the public Internet), and there must be congestion before it actually works.